# ubuntu server 14.04 xvfb japanese characters as squares after release upgrade

Tags: fonts, japanese, xvfb, electron

Why did Japanese fonts suddenly stop displaying correctly? 
Very difficult tough complex situation, at one time this gaggle was working, broke after a platform upgrade that coincided with a new code release. It could be the code, but that code works fine running on Mac or Ubuntu Desktop development o/s.

ENVIRONMENT:

- Ubuntu 14.04 Server Headless upgraded (on Cloud Foundry: no sudo    privs)
- PDF generation using Electron Chromium    win.webContents.printToPDF
- Electron version 1.6.2 (tried newer 3.0.13)

Not having Root at the container makes this problem/solution difficult. 
Not having control or insight to the patching of the underlying o/s further aggravates the indeterminate nature.

We forked the Pivotal CF node buildpack and implemented something similar to this code snippet in our compile phase of the build pack (sample: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-xvfb-google-chrome/blob/master/bin/compile ) using a Aptfile in the application to specify which apt-get install packages would be installed as the local user.

This bag of insanity worked fine, until last month, when Japanese characters stop rendering correctly. One potentially critical thing that changed was the hosting folks upgraded the base o/s for the container from Ubuntu 14.04

$ `uname -a`

BEFORE magical upgrade fairies: 
`Linux e4e7267c 4.4.0-75-generic #96~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 11:06:30 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

AFTER evil upgrade gremlins: 
`Linux c3fa6d0b 4.15.0-38-generic #41~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 10 20:16:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Strangely enough the AFTER 16.04 shows the release is still Trusty: 
$ `lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available. 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu 
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS 
Release:    14.04 
Codename:   trusty
```

---

Did something change in the dependency from 14.04 --> 16.04 upgrade libraries? 
Did Xvfb change how it handled font paths and lookups (X.org under the hood)?

The fonts are installed into local user account as: 
$ ls -ltr app/.apt/usr/share/fonts/X11/

```
total 84
drwxr-xr-x 2 vcap vcap  4096 Jan  2 14:19 util
drwxr-xr-x 2 vcap vcap  4096 Jan  2 14:19 Type1
drwxr-xr-x 2 vcap vcap 20480 Jan  2 14:19 misc
-rw-r--r-- 1 vcap vcap     2 Jan  2 14:19 fonts.dir
drwxr-xr-x 3 vcap vcap  4096 Jan  2 14:19 encodings
drwxr-xr-x 2 vcap vcap  4096 Jan  2 14:19 cyrillic
drwxr-xr-x 2 vcap vcap 16384 Jan  2 14:19 75dpi
drwxr-xr-x 2 vcap vcap 16384 Jan  2 14:19 100dpi
```

Part of the hacking to get this to work involves using sed to replace the hardcoded path reference in Xvfb to use the local user's directory path.

Maybe that functionality changed in the new upgraded version of Xvfb.

Any thoughts on further troubleshooting, hacking tricks, or potential causes/solutions to this would be appreciated.

[image]